# what's the point using Mockito to mock objects?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

This is a mockito example from mockito website:
It mocks a List object and test it.
What's the point doing this? what's the benefits from this?
Why can't i just instantiated a list?

```
 //Let's import Mockito statically so that the code looks clearer
 import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

 //mock creation
 List mockedList = mock(List.class);

 //using mock object
 mockedList.add("one");
 mockedList.clear();

 //verification
 verify(mockedList).add("one");
 verify(mockedList).clear();
```

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783722/when-using-mokito-what-is-the-difference-between-the-actual-object-and-the-mock/28783849#28783849

Comment: You are right, though, that _the specific case of List_ is probably a bad example. There's generally no reason to mock a List. (It was probably picked because people are familiar with the interface.)